# Limit iCloud Photo Library space usage on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos.app

Is there anyway limiting the amount of space iCloud Photo Library uses?

It seems to use as much space as is available on my iPhone l

I really like having the HQ pics on my Mac and I like how it's done automatically but I don't need all the photos on my phone.

I have set it to optimise space usage but I notice it just uses all available space.

Can I limit this?

Comment: As far as I know it isn't possible. The optimization is using the available space but should leave space for other things. That is as long as the previews doesn't require all the space I guess. Had problems myself but as I noticed over time the space it used did change with other things I installed or saved to the phone.